# Intellij "cannot resolve symbol" after installing spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I've recently installed the plugin "spring boot assistant" into my Intellij. When I was trying to run an old java file that I've completed before, a lot of the symbols were displayed as "cannot resolve symbol".

This is what my file looks like.
[image]

I think this might have something to do with maven, but I dont know how to fix it since there's no errors with running the program before installing spring-boot and maven. I've just started learning spring boot so I'm still unfamiliar with the functions. Please help me.

Comment: Try using ` mvn -version` command to see which java version it is using

Answer (score 4):

Some plugins might mess up with the project settings. First of all, try to invalidate cache: `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart...`. Confirm with `Invalidate and Restart`. It takes a while but is worth a try.

If it doesn't work your SDK is not set: Open `File` -> `Project Structure...` and navigate to `Project` and add a Project SDK and the Project language level you need (you might want to navigate to your SDK saved in the system instead).

[image]

It is also worth to try checking up the language levels:

- `File` -> `Project Structure...` and navigate to `Modules`.

  Check the `Language level` of each module.
- `File` -> `Settings` and navigate to `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Java Compiler`.

  Check the `Target bytecode version` of each module.

Comment: It might also be crucial, that the language level is set correctly for the project and the potential sub modules

Comment: Yes, thank for a note. I have added the information about what's worth the check.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have issues with resolving absolutely basic Java stuff - try going into `Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Project` and check if you have an SDK defined for your project.